# Передача данных из laravel при помощи compact в фронтенд на Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

каким образом я могу получить данные из compact() в компоненте Vue.

```
 public function show(Request $request){
        $orderData = OrderData::where('id',$request->id)->first();
        return $orderData;
  }
```

Comment: Извиняюсь ,исправил

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

**[compact](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.compact.php)** - это обычная функция php для работы с массивами.

Данная запись `return view('reports.single', compact('orderData'));` равнозначна записи:

```
return view('reports.single', [
  'orderData' => $orderData
]);
```

**Передача данных из Laravel в компоненты vuejs**

**1** Банальная передача данных компоненту через свойства (pros):

```
<example-component :orders='@json($orderData)'></example-component>
```

Теперь в компоненте `resources\js\components\ExampleComponent.vue` должны быть доступны данные:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'orders'
  ],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$props.orders)
  }
}
</script>
```

**2** Пример посложнее. Если вы используете наследование шаблонов в Laravel, то в главном шаблоне (например, `layouts/app.blade.php`) указываете:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
  <head>
    ... Тут остальная разметка
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <script>
      "use strict";

      // Объявляем глобальный контейнер для данных
      window.vueData = {}
    </script>

    {{-- Объявляем стек, к которому дочерние шаблоны могут "стыковать" свои данные --}}
    @stack('vue-data')

    {{-- Подключение основных скриптов, как пример --}}
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

В дочернем шаблоне `reports/single.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <example-component></example-component>
@endsection

{{-- Отправляем необходимые данные в стек --}}
@push('vue-data')
  <script>
    // Объявляем новое свойство.
    Object.defineProperty(vueData, 'orderData', {
      writable: false,
      configurable: false,
      value: @json($orderData)
    })
  </script>
@endpush
```

Теперь в компоненте `resources\js\components\ExampleComponent.vue` должны быть доступны данные:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      orders: vueData.orderData
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.orders)
  }
}

</script>
```