# как вставить цикл php laravel в Vue?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как мне вставить цикл в виде (php laravel) в Vue. Мне необходимо передать данные из цикла во vue чтобы данные из цикла отобразились в выпадающем списке

Цикл

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address" class="col-form-label">Адрес</label>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
       <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="address" value="">
           @foreach ($regions as $current)
               @if($current->parent_id)
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('cabinet.adverts.create.region', [$category, $current]) }}">{{ $current->name }}</a>
                    </li>
               @endif
           @endforeach

          @if ($errors->has('address'))
              <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong></span>
          @endif
    </div>
                        
  </div>
   </div>
```

```html
public function advert(Category $category, Region $region = null)
    {

        $regions = Region::where($region)->orderBy('name')->get();

        return view('cabinet.adverts.create.advert', compact('category', 'region', 'regions'));
    }
```

Html

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select</h1>
  <v-select :options="options"></v-select>
</div>
```

Js

```js
new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                options: [
                    1,4,5,11
                ]
            }
        })
```

Песочни[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/NpwrQO)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975190/256824 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976861/256824

Comment: не получилось к сожалению разобраться.. не понимаю как мне в данном случае цикл перенести в options? не могли бы вы показать на моем примере как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: или можете подсказать оптимальное решение мне необходимо чтобы был инпут в который можно было вводить текст и появлялся нужный город который по данному циклу выводится

i.imgur.com/OFyUJve.png

Comment: Вы бы дамп `dump($regions)` пары-тройки сущностей приложили к вопросу, если хотите конкретики.

Comment: https://codepen.io/russsiq/pen/VwZooVO

Comment: за ддешил $regions http://i.imgur.com/2bP5B3X.png

Comment: так же обновил в первом посте html и добавил контроллер для полного понимания картины

Comment: вот что сейчас $current->name выводит i.imgur.com/OFyUJve.png

Comment: дополнительно прикладываю видео

То что выводится
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2WQY/5aVDx8iWU

Коллеккция
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3dFn/dpBALsSDD

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7SLk8r6.png

Comment: @РустамГимранов на собаку ругается и в конце не хватает чего то http://i.imgur.com/fh3FhkV.png

попробовал вставил все в один вид для теста option.name не находит...
 http://i.imgur.com/PuifoGl.png
http://i.imgur.com/tkfFaMY.png

Comment: Перед тем как продолжить изучите этот ответ, там в конце еще ссылка на официальную документацию. Как мне показалось у вас несколько сумбурное представление https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/979935/256824